# How to predict the character in this k-means

Tags: matlab, image-processing, k-means, predict, handwriting-recognition

Iam doing hand written character recognition 
After executing i got output like [This](http://oi62.tinypic.com/a292tf.jpg)

My aim is to predict the character of the output image file like test and i used this k-means [File](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37503-k-means-clustering-algorithm)

Any one please help me to predict the character of the output image. This would help me to proceed further steps in my project thanks in advance.

Comment: You have found and run an example that locates the centres of possible letters. Unfortunately Stack Overflow cannot give you a guide to creating your own OCR system starting from there, we need something more direct and simple to answer. Please explain in detail what is blocking you taking the next step in your project. "I don't know how" is not useful - please take time to give details - what is it that you do know already, and where *exactly* are you having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Performing OCR requires a fairly large training set of existing letters for k-means to operate on. Using k-means for this application would involve clustering the images themselves (a single image would be a single data point), not just clustering the pixels a given image. A good place to start might be the [MNIST dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) for digit recognition.

Also, k-means is an unsupervised learning algorithm which probably won't give great results for OCR. The classes it creates will likely mix similar letters like `a` and `o` together, create multiple classes for the same letter written in different sytles, and ignore other letters completely.

You should look into using a supervised algorithm where the training data is labelled, like k-nearest neighbours. This way you will know what the classes are ahead of time and have much better success in the testing phase.